# Statistics: what's in and what's not?

Tags: 2010

There are some default statistics available out of the box in SharePoint. But now I have a customer requesting user based statistics. Things they want to see include: when did a user log in, how long do users stay online, how often did a user log in per month / year, things like that.

As far as I know, these things aren't available ootb. If that's true: what would be a good way to offer this functionality to my customer? Are there 3rd party solutions available? Google Analytics? Extension to the default SharePoint statistics?

Comment: Do you mean SharePoint 2007 or SharePoint 2010? The statistics functionality has had quite a makeover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just put Google Analytics on one of my 2007 sites and it's great information in conjunction with the auditing data we're gathering.  The 2010 web analytics within Sharepoint can get you some of the information, but not to the degree of what GA will offer.

If they want specifics on user activity, like frequency of login, you'll want to use auditing so you can track that on a per user basis.

Comment: Can you share any information on what you need to do this? I'm not familiar with GA (apart from the name) so I'd like to know what effort this would take. Sounds promising though, maybe even a little overkill.

Comment: Sure.  Sign up for Google Analytics and you'll receive some javascript you can add you your page.  The site I wanted to track was statistics on one single level web application we have.  So I cracked open Sharepoint Designer and placed the javascript into the master page.  It reports the data back to Google and you can see the stats the next day.

Answer (score 0):

I think that kind of user activities can be logged by IIS. A summary of SP2010 web analytics is listed here: http://www.itidea.nl/index.php/web-analytics/